# How to print a custom message on console after running tests on Xcode 5

Tags: xctest

Is there a way to print a custom message after the output generated after running tests on Xcode 5?

The output ends in something like this:

> **Executed 328 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 4.342 (4.539) seconds**

I would like to be able to print something on the console after this. I tried to run a script on the build phase and a post-action on the test section of the target scheme but I don't know how to print on the console using shell.